# java.lang.NullPointerException while getting data from db using @Query in spring JPA. Though query returns data in MySql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, nullpointerexception

I am trying to get data from DB using pincode and cityName but I am getting null pointer exception.
I tried to run the query in MySql. It returns correct result. 
pincode and cityName are getting correct parameters.

```
@Component
public interface GeoMasterDao extends PagingAndSortingRepository<GeoMaster, Long>,JpaSpecificationExecutor<GeoMaster>{

    @Query("select p from GeoMaster p where p.pincode =:pincode and p.cityName =:cityName")
    GeoMaster findByPincodeAndCityName(@Param("pincode") String pincode, @Param("cityName") String cityName);
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "geo_master")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("isBlocked")
@Getter
@Setter
public class GeoMaster extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column
    private String countryId;

    @Column
    private String districtId;

    @Column
    private String stateId;

    @Column
    private String pincode;

    @Column
    private String cityId;

    @Column
    private String cityName;

}
```

I am calling it using `GeoMaster gm = gmDao.findByPincodeAndCityName(pincode, cityName);` and here I am getting NullPointerException. findByPincodeAndCityName is having correct values in parameters.

Comment: Where do you get the NPE? Can you please post the stacktrace? And how do you inject: gmDao

Comment: i think you dont need to use the query annotation just write the fuction like this :     GeoMaster findByPincodeAndCityName String pincode,  String cityName); check this : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: `@Autowired
 private GeoMasterDao gmDao;`  I have added and I am calling it from `service.fetchGeoMasterData(pincode, city, request);` where service is created using new keyword `ServiceImpl service= new ServiceImpl();` and `ServiceImpl` has  `@Autowired
 private GeoMasterDao gmDao` and `GeoMaster gm = gmDao.findByPincodeAndCityName(pincode, cityName);`

Comment: If you instantiate your service manually, I think the ```@Autowired``` is useless. You should have a ```@Service``` annotation on your service implementation and let Spring create the service and inject the Dao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null pointer exception is probably happening because `gmDao` is null, rather than some problem with the query.  You should check to make sure that your DAO object is being autowired correctly.  You should have something like this:

```
@Autowired
public GeoMasterDao gmDao;
```

in the class which is executing the query.

Comment: I have added it. I didn't add it here.

Comment: Then your autowiring is failing.  Try debugging your code to verify what my answer says.